# Mobile jQuery listview clarification

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

I would like to design a page something similar to the following one.
[image]

This is my html markup.

```
<div data-role="content">  
    <div data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
<ul>
    <li><a href="www.google.com">Google</a> </li>
    <li><a href="www.yahoo.com">Yahoo </a> </li>
     <li><a href="www.codeplex.com">MSDN </a> </li>
</ul>
  </div>
  </div>
```

I am getting the follwing output.

[image]

What is the issue with my html mark up. I have referred the necessary javascript libraries and CSS files.

The header is holding the followin references.

```
<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you suppose to apply `data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true"` to `<ul>` instead of `<div>`
try changing

```
<div data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
```

to

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
```